# How to open a remote folder to edit all files within using winscp/cyberduck?

Tags: ssh, sublimetext2, winscp, adobe-brackets, cyberduck

I connect to a remote folder via winscp/cyberduck, to edit a file. I can open the file with an editor of choice like sublimetext or brackets but I cannot seem to open a folder and edit the files within the folder, this option is not available.

How to open remote folder so I can edit all files within the folder (not having to open each file individually) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sshfs` might be your friend. I heard there was some version for Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

In WinSCP, select all files in the folder before using the *Edit* command.